# Puxar valor de uma coluna com select mysql ao php

Tags: php, mysql, select

Olá!

Eu tenho esse banco:

```
SELECT * FROM player_index WHERE player_index.empire
```

Retorno da query: https://prnt.sc/pk8k1u

E tenho esse codigo abaixo,o valor da coluna empire deveria ficar em: `<?=$players[$i][1]?>`

```js
<table id="ranking_evento" data-ranking="player">
<?
$novo_vetor = mysqli_query(server_player(),"SELECT * FROM player WHERE player.name NOT LIKE '[%]%' ORDER BY evento DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($novo_vetor)) {
?>
        <tr class="ranking_table_row">
         <td class="ranking_icon"></td>
   <td class="ranking_playername"><?=$row['name']?></td>
   <td class="ranking_points">
            <div class="ranking_points_title"><?=l(8);?></div>
   <div class="ranking_points_value"><?=$row['level']?></div>
            <div class="top5kill"><div class="ranking_points_title"><?=l(244);?></div>
   <div class="ranking_points_value"><?=$row['evento']?></div></div>
            <td class="full_ranking_<?=$players[$i][1]?>_kingdom" style="background-size: 35px;"></td>
   </td>
  </tr>
<?PHP } ?>
 </table>
```

Ocorre que eu preciso inserir os valores de uma outra coluna de outra tabela nessa linha:

```
<td class="full_ranking_<?=$players[$i][1]?>_kingdom" style="background-size: 35px;"></td>
```

Onde esta  é onde deve ficar o valor.

Na imagem abaixo eu mostro um espécie de top5 com orde by.o top5 acima esta correto. As bandeiras é onde eu estou mexendo.

o primeiro top5 esta completo com as bandeiras correta, se reparar no "colombiano" ele tem a bandeira azul,se reparar no "Deus" ele tem a bandeira amarela, se repara nos demais 3 vermelhos ok e esta correto de acordo ao banco.

Se você olhar segundo top5 verá que todas bandeiras estao vermelhas onde na verdade o "colombiano" é azul,o Deus é amarelo etc..o valor fica sempre o mesmo.

https://prnt.sc/pk5q2c

Aqui esta o codigo do top5 que esta ok:

```js
    <table id="ranking_table" data-ranking="player">
<?PHP for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ ?>
        <tr class="ranking_table_row">
            <td class="ranking_icon"></td>
            <td class="ranking_playername"><?=$players[$i][0]?></td>
            <td class="ranking_points">
            <div class="ranking_points_title"><?=l(8);?></div>
            <div class="ranking_points_value"><?=$players[$i][2]?></div>
      <div class="top5kill"><div class="ranking_points_title"><?=l(244);?></div>
   <div class="ranking_points_value"><?=$players[$i][6]?></div></div>
         <td class="full_ranking_<?=$players[$i][1]?>_kingdom" style="background-size: 35px;"></td>
   </td>
  </tr>
<?PHP } ?>
    </table>
```

Espero ter sido claro obrigado pela ajuda de sempre.

Comment: Poderia compartilhar o retorno do select SELECT * FROM player_index WHERE player_index.empire?

Comment: aqui esta: https://prnt.sc/pk8k1u
Outra coisa se eu colocar <?=$row['level']?> no lugar de <?=$players[$i][1]?> eu consigo puxar o valor correto de outra tabela. Então eu preciso por <?=$row['empire']?>. <?=$players[$i][1]?> me retorna sempre 1.

Comment: então a variável $players é retorno dessa query, certo?

Comment: Na verdade Juliano essa query só dei exemplo de onde esta os dados que eu quero puxar. Não consigo puxar o retorno dela. Eu puxei esse <?=$players[$i][1]?> de outra pagina que eu tenho com a intenção de puxar esse mesmo valor.

Comment: Acredio que esse player vem puxado daqui: https://pastebin.com/U4jhqBcA Esse codigo se encontra em outra pagina que todos os dados que eu quero puxar. O codigo que eu quero colocar é na index.php esses codigos estão todos em player.php.

Comment: então, é que o correto é o valor empire vir da interação do for da variável $row

Comment: O ideal seria você utilizar um JOIN na query para trazer o valor empire caso não tenha na tabela que está utilizando

Comment: Isso mesmo o correto é vim de $row

Comment: Quando eu declaro <?=$row['empire']?> não me retorna nada. quando eu coloco <?=$row['level']?> puxa os dados da tabela player corretamente. Ai vem a pergunta, como sei de onde o $row esta puxando?

Comment: o $row está puxando os dados do select da variável $novo_vetor

Comment: Rapaz não é que eu consegui :) vc me deu uma luz então eu fiz assim e resultou, ve o que acha: https://pastebin.com/tu3D9mP4

Comment: isso mesmo, agora só utilizar esse valor dentro do while

Comment: Ficou perfeito! Poderia responder a pergunta sobre o JOIN para que eu marque como resposta que solucionou?

Comment: Coloquei como resposta @Renato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) para poder pegar a coluna `empire` da outra tabela relacionada, podendo assim, utilizar esse valor resultante do `JOIN` no `WHILE`